# React useSelector first returns undefined, then returns object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to extract data from state. I'm using redux.

`const {currentPost } = useSelector(state => state.posts)`

I expected to get an object with properties. Instead I get couple of undefined and then I get an object.
These undefined on the start causes that I can't destructure further like `const {currentPost: {id} } = useSelector(state => state.posts)`and returns error that it can't read property of undefined.
These posts are obtained by API.

I've tried to workaround it by use a function which checks if this `currentPost` is undefined and then pass null into these properties. However it's not suitable for project and this solution is error prone.

Comment: `useSelector(state => state ? state.posts : {})`?

Comment: The thing is I have to get some properties from it to make some logic in component

Comment: Is `state.posts` being filled in after the application has started?  If it exists on startup, then the `useSelector` should return whatever's there immediately.

Comment: But what's wrong with creating a separate selector function and check if state.posts exists? Does it have to be a one liner?

Comment: @markerikson Yeah, this state is filled. The problem is these undefined object that appears first, and then object is loaded. If I console.log it it shows 2/3 times undefined and then object. However it's pecular that if I do ```const {currentPost } = useSelector(state => state.posts)``` then it's ok, if I do ```const {currentPost: {id} } = useSelector(state => state.posts)``` it returns error immediately.

Comment: @kinduser I've done something like this: ```const getId = (currentPost) => {
    if (currentPost === undefined){
      const id = null
      return id
    } else {
      const {id} = currentPost
      return id
    }
  }
  const postId = getId(currentPost)``` it works, but this solution causes some errors

Comment: What errors does it cause?

Comment: @kinduser after canceling post it says it cannot read property of null

Comment: @ArcMech If `state.posts.currentPost` is only available after some api call is made, you need to initialize it with `null` (not `undefined`) or `{}` in the reducer. In the react component, you need to write conditionals to check when `currentPost` is available, and only then destructure further and render stuff. This is a very common thing in react/redux apps.

Comment: what is "postsReducer" initial state?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I get more experience I want to share my knowledge for future young frontend developers

I'm using `redux-toolkit` https://redux-toolkit.js.org/
These undefined values are from async operations, so its their behaviour that sometimes before promise is completed return undefined value.

To overcome it and write stable code there is a need to add default values. In redux-toolkit you can use

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'posts',
  initialState: {
    currentPosts: {
      value: {
        name: ''
      }
    },
    posts: []
  },
  reducers: {
    ...reducers
    },
})
```

In that case you'll get Object currentPosts, which is not undefined.

Comment: Hello @ArcMech, more than a year late but i can't seem to find a fix to my scenario. Would you mind taking a look at it please? I am using the traditional Redux. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68018044/using-data-retrieved-from-reduxs-useselector-throws-as-undefined

Comment: Sure @domster but link is expired/deleted. Does your question is still valid?

Comment: thanks i appreciate it! i found a workaround for it! thank you so much! :)